# Por que o programa não reconhece o "N"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class primao:
    from random import randrange

    def __init__(self, N=randrange(2,100), divisor=0, pontos=0, laco=True, prova_cabal= N%divisor):
        self.N= N
        self.divisor= divisor
        self.pontos= pontos
        self.laco= laco
        self.prova_cabal= prova_cabal

    def gerar_primo(self):
        for i in range(1,self.N,+1):
            self.divisor += 1                       
            if self.prova_cabal == 0:
                self.pontos += 1
            if self.pontos > 2:
                self.laco= False
        if laco == False:
            gerar_primo()   
        if pontos <= 2:
            self.laco = True
            return self.N


A= primao()
A.N_Primo()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está sendo gerado porque você não inicializou as variáveis `N` e `divisor` na sua classe ou fora antes de serem usadas para definir o parâmetro `prova_cabal = N % divisor`.

Eu não sei qual o seu objetivo com esse código, mas se você inicializar essas variáveis, o erro será eliminado. Exemplo:

```
class Primao(object):
    from random import randrange

    N = 1
    divisor = 1

    def __init__(self, N = randrange(2,100), divisor=0, pontos=0, laco=True, prova_cabal = N % divisor):

        self.N = N
        self.divisor = divisor
        self.pontos = pontos
        self.laco = laco
        self.prova_cabal = prova_cabal

    # Código restante...
```

Fora isso o seu código está cheio de erro. Você está chamando o método `N_Primo()` que não existe, você esqueceu de usar `self` ao chamar o atributo `laco` e o método `gerar_primo`, e mesmo com esses detalhes corrigidos, o seu código ainda gera o seguinte erro:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Esse erro está sendo gerado porque você ultrapassa o máximo de chamadas permitidas do mesmo método em Python.

Sugiro que revise o seu código direito, procurando por erros de digitação para corrigi-los e melhore a lógica do seu código.